# Error:java: error: release version 5 not supported

Tags: java, hibernate

Me podeis ayudar a solucionar  el error que me sale en java `Error:java: error: release version 5 not supported`

En el pom tengo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bases-de-datos-2019-2020</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejemplo-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Imagen del project Structure y las diferentes opciones que tengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el problema procede de ahí pero no sé como solucionarlo cambiando lo mínimo la estructura del pom.xml

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no se especifica nada en el pom.xml, Maven implica Java 5.

Hay varias formas de especificar la versión de Java:

- Añadir properties.
  Hasta JDK 8 puedes usar:

  ```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  ```

  A partir de JDK 9, también está *maven.compiler.release*, y ahora los números son enteros:

  ```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>
  ```

  Se puede seguir usando *source* y *target*, pero se recomienda usar *release*.
- Configurar el *maven-compiler-plugin*:

  Los valores indicados arriba se pasan a la configuración por defecto del plugin de compilación de maven, pero puedes modificar la configuración dle plugin directamente. Es más engorroso así que no pongo ejemplo, pero puedes [buscarlo por internet](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version)

Comment: Gracias !! Lo miraré